# OEPE auto generated EAR, Weblogic and Openfaces

Tags: eclipse, ear, openfaces

I have a web application with JSF 2.0 support. I use Eclipse Indigo with Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) as IDE. The problem is when i add openfaces 3.0 to my project i get an error when opening a page:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Second notification for the same
>   phase in the same request occurred. phaseId.ordinal: 1; phaseId =
>   RESTORE_VIEW 1; More than one
>   org.openfaces.component.validation.ValidatorPhaseListener is found to
>   be registered (2). Check that only one JSF implementation is deployed
>   with your application's classpath, and openfaces.jar is not duplicated
>   in application's and server's libraries."

When i export EAR with standard eclipse tool and deploy it on Weblogic via console everything works fine. The same happens if I set "Publish as an exploded archive" in Weblogic properties. So, it seems that the problem is in the way OEPE makes and uses `_auto_generated_ear_` which is used by application when "Publish as a virtual application" is set. I tried to work with exploded archive but it's nearly impossible because hot-swap doesn't work and publishing time is just tremendous: i can make a cup of tea and drink it while application is published. So, is it possible to make some modifications in the way `_auto_generated_ear_` of OEPE uses resources?